Identifying an IC
I have this item as pictures (board) which shows U1 chip that I am trying to identify.

The chip has no markings. I probed the board and found that the pins as follows controls which LED in the RGB LED is on.

I would like to repurpose the item and several others like it by re-programming the microcontroller for the board so its more useful to me.
Operation is currently as follows:
Press Sw1 to turn on
Press Sw1 again to change light from white to red
Press Sw1 again to change light from red to green
Press Sw1 again to change light from green to blue
Press Sw1 again to turn off
What I am looking for is something simpler like:
Press Sw1 to turn on default to red
Press Sw1 again to change light from red to green
Press Sw1 again to toggle between red and green
Long press SW1 (5 seconds or so) to turn off.
I have written the arduino code that does this functionality. I just don't know what this IC U1 is. I am pretty certain I have probed the pin out correctly.
I thought it might be an ATTiny.
Suggestions on how to go about finding out what this chip is and how to program it with a programmer tool (as in what tool!)
Help is appreciated.

Just to manage expectations, reprogramming the chip to do what you are describing is probably not possible. Desoldering and replacing with an entirely new micro is probably the only way you'd be able to pull that off.

Even that would be an option, i'd still need to know what sort of kit I need because I have FTDI for arduino but no other type of flash tool.

@MarkGiblin your post is about identifying the IC ... it is not about determining what sort of kit you need ... if you have a different question, then edit your post accordingly

The IC could be any IC with similar pinout. If you want to program a chip, buy a new one which you can program and has same pinout. That IC may not be an MCU, or if it is, it's likely one time programmable, and could be some weird MCU used only by that manufacturer so nobody has data sheet or tools to program it. It literally cannot be known which MCU it is, unless you melt away the plastic and see the silicon die to compare it with other MCUs.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Pretty long shot, but some Chinese MCU manufacturers like Padauk put the markings on the underside of the package. You could desolder it and see if there is anything written there.


I thought it might be an AT Tiny.

Almost certainly not. Microchip (formerly Atmel) won't sell anyone an AtTiny without markings.
This is very likely a cheapest-grade microcontroller either with mask ROM, or a one-time programmable memory, so that the pin used for programming can be used as an output afterwards.
You will have to replace it with a different microcontroller, and possibly specific output drivers on a separate board.
There's absolutely no indication what this is, nobody can tell you, but even if they could, it would almost certainly not be possible to reprogram it, and very certainly not as an Arduino.

I am more interested in what controller the pin out matches or can you suggest something to replace it?
The item is a little lamp with a dome top that is opaque to allow the set colour to illuminate the immediate area.

no, I can't, because as said, you might need to figure out what things that controller drives. I actually addressed this in my answer already!

Its not driving anything other than LED's from a 4.5v source.

that can mean a lot of current. Which not every microcontroller can source. In fact, many microcontrollers aren't even compatible with 4.5 V IO.

But thats the voltage and the LED's are switched via mosfet. There is one RGB chip and 6 white LED (in parallel)

@MarkGiblin again, that might be fine, it might not be fine with whatever MCU you choose. Can't tell you, I don't know your circuit.

First compare its pinout to ATtiny microcontrollers since it fits the description of a small microcontroller controlling the RGB LEDs. I'll use a USBasp programmer or an Arduino as an ISP to try reprogramming it.
Here's my plan:
I’ll connect the programmer to the chip’s pins (MOSI, MISO, SCK, RESET, Vcc, GND).
I’ll use the Arduino IDE to upload my custom code and check if it works.
If it uploads successfully, I’ll confirm the chip is an ATtiny or similar.
If needed, I’ll use AVRDUDE to identify the chip further...
